# request, response words for SOAPContext

Tags: java, soap

Is it possible in a SOAP Messaging application to write the following?

```
public void nameSOAP(Envelope env, SOAPContext request, SOAPContext response) throws ...
```

I mean can the words request, response be used?

Comment: Sure, as request and response are no reserved keywords in java.

Comment: and the word env can be changed by any other, too?

Comment: Yes. Have look at the [official list of reserved java keywords](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)